# Preg_split, how to keep delimiter?

Tags: php, html, regex, delimiter, preg-split

I'm trying to keep preg_split delimiter (< tr > and < /tr >) without separate it in a new array position and can't figure it out. So any help will be appreciated.

I'm trying to take every row from the next html code and put it in a different array position:

```
<tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr><tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>
```

Here's what I've got:

```
array_unique(preg_split('[<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>]',$table,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

If I do a var_dump of my array this code shows :

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "<td> one column </td><td>second column</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(43) "<td> one column </td><td>second column</td>"
  }
```

And what I want is:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(52) "<tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>"
    [1]=>
    string(52) "<tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>"
  }
```

Beforehand, thanks a lot for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture also the `<tr>` tag. Since you're are using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` parameter, this would return also the characters which are being captured.

```
array_unique(preg_split('[(<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>)]',$table,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

**Example 1:**

```
$st = '<tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr><tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>';
$match = preg_split('[(<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>)]',$st,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>
    [1] => <tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>
)
```

**Example 2:**

```
$st = '<tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr><tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>';
$match = array_unique(preg_split('[(<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>)]',$st,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tr><td> one column </td><td>second column</td></tr>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use preg_split for this. You want to use preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('[<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>]', $table, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$rows = $matches[0];
```

Few questions though: why would you use array_unique? And why would you want to parse HTML using regular expressions? Use something like xpath instead.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Your solution also works! I'm using array_unique because I'm filtering the array result to not store duplicated rows. I'm building the array data with a table from PHPexcel and deleting duplicated rows.